# How can I remove the highlight bar in kTikZ/qTikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been asking this question already in KDE and Qt communities but it seems that I can't find a kTikZ or qTikZ user there, so I thought to ask it here too because maybe there are kTikz users here.

The problem is very simple, I don't want the highlight bar which automatically appears where the cursor is placed to highlight the current line.

I can't find the option to configure the bar presence or to change its color. Problem is that my text color is set to white/gray and the bar color is also white/gray, so I can't read the line where the cursor is actually placed.

I don't want to change the text color because it is bound to an high contrast theme I need for my poor eyesight. The problem is just with the kTikZ bar which I don't want.

I hope this is not too OT but its very difficult to find LaTeX users on the web and kTikZ users especially. I saw there are already questions on how to use software like emacs, Vim, etc. so I hope you'll accept my question too.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I guess a MWE is not appropriate in this case. Please delete your comments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm afraid that question is borderline off-topic on TeX.SE; It may get migrated to another SE site where you'd be more likely to get answer.

Comment: I saw you have lots of questions about highlighting in emacs which are similar to mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=emacs+highlight so I decided to post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature you don't like is hardcoded and can be removed only modifying the source code and recompiling it. There is no option in the GUI for this task.

Now, if you're a windows user you're out of luck since I have no idea how you can recomplile a .exe file.

On the other hand, if you're a Linux user you can get rid of the feature with the following steps. They work for both KTikz and QTikZ (they're the same app, actually):

1. Remove any version of KTikZ/QTikZ installed via a package manager
2. Download the .tar package of, say, KTikZ
3. Extract the tarball and open `ktikz/app/tikzeditor.cpp` with your favorite editor
4. go to line 69, which looks like:

   ```
   m_highlightCurrentLineColor = lineColor.darker(105);
   else
   m_highlightCurrentLineColor = altLineColor;
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   m_highlightCurrentLineColor = Qt::transparent;
   else
   m_highlightCurrentLineColor = Qt::transparent;
   ```
5. Save the file and compile. (see the `INSTALL` file provided by the tarball)

**Before:**[image]

**After:**[image]